# Error starting ipython?

Tags: xubuntu, python, ipython

When I start `ipython`, the following error gets printed in the screen:

> [TerminalIPythonApp] ERROR | Exception while loading config file
>   /home/cossio/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line
>   514, in _load_config_files
>       config = loader.load_config()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/loader.py",
>   line 425, in load_config
>       self._read_file_as_dict()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/loader.py",
>   line 478, in _read_file_as_dict
>       py3compat.execfile(conf_filename, namespace)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py",
>   line 224, in execfile
>       builtin_mod.execfile(filename, *where)
>
> File "/home/cossio/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py", line
>   535, in
>
> ```
> IPythonWidget.buffer_size=999999 NameError: name 'IPythonWidget' is not defined
> ```

In spite of this, `ipython` starts, and I can use it. But I don't know what is the cause of this error?

I am using Xubuntu 15.04, Python 2.7.9, and IPython 2.3.0.